# GWT Null objects in @UiHandler methods

Tags: gwt, mvp, uibinder

I am using GWT 2.4 with MVP. 
Here is my view object:

```
public class LoginWidget extends Composite implements LoginWidgetView {

interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, LoginWidget> {
}

private static final Binder BINDER = GWT.create(Binder.class);

@UiField Anchor settings;

public LoginWidget() {
    initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@UiHandler("settings")
void handleSettingsClick(ClickEvent e) {
    presenter.showSettings();
}

private Presenter presenter;

@Override
public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}
```

}

I am setting the view´s presenter by

```
...
getLoginWidget().setPresenter(new LoginWidgetPresenter(placeController));
```

LoginWidgetPresenter of course implements the view´s Presenter interface. But when I click on the settings anchor, the presenter reference is still null, so presenter.showSettings() throws a NullPointerException. 
I suppose that after calling the LoginWidget´s constructor and initializing the widget by

```
initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
```

the click handling code in my @UiHandler("settings") method ignores changes to the used objects like my presenter object?? 
Is there a way to set the presenter object after calling the initWidget() method? 
Or is it possible to customize the @UiHandler/initWidget()-behaviour that I can set my presenter afterwards?

Thanks, Manuel

Comment: Have you debugged it? with breakpoints in both `setPresenter` and `handleSettingsClick`, and making sure they're called in the correct order and on the same `LoginWidget` instance?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve already debugged it. `setPresenter()` is called with a _real_ presenter instance. But in `handleSettingsClick()` the component´s `presenter` class variable is null. So I think it has to be a different `LoginWidget` instance, on which I set the `presenter`. But that´s what I have to look for. I just wanted to make sure that it usually should work the way, I´ve implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

I implement MVP in another way and UIBinder work for my. Maybe if you pass the LoginWidgetPresenter in LoginWidget constructor it works.

```
public LoginWidget(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
    initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
}
...
getLoginWidget(new LoginWidgetPresenter(placeController));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in your approach you have to know about the placeController (or maybe an optional request factory) passing it in constructor when creating the widget. If I want to create the widget inside of another view component, I must make request factory and place controller available there, and I think this is not what MVP is recommending? Or maybe I missed something...

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of things, which could have gone wrong. The easiest thing is to try to debug your code, by putting breakpoints `handleSettings` and 'setPresenter' methods.
My guess is that one of following is happening:

- `setPresenter` is never actually called

or

- `getLoginWidget()` always returns a new instance of the widget, and it is quite possible that you are setting presenter on one instance of login widget, but displaying totally different instance of the widget

or

- You have `getLoginWidget().setPresenter(null)` somewhere in your code

or any other guess. It is much more easier to debug, and see for yourself, where and how presenter instance is passed. Anyway, `UiBinder` will not erase your field values (unless it is modified by someone else to make fun of you)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in the comment above I´ve already debugged it. `setPresenter` is called after `LoginWidget` has been created via deferred binding. The `getLoginWidget` is just a simple get-method on a parent UI component (`LoginWidget` is just a `@UiField` on the parent component), so actually there can´t be any more instances of `LoginWidget`. The parent component is implemented as Singleton. But as in the comment above it´s good to know that `@UiHandler` should support setting my presenter object after `initWidget(...)` has been called.

Comment: @TonySkulk Well, I can only say one thing. From the code you provided, i can see no problem at all. Standard normal UiBinder can't do anything to the private fields. By the way, how did you debugged it? Did you set break-points to the both `setPresenter` and `handleSettingsClick` and validated that they are both called in correct sequence and `setPresenter is called with correct value?

Comment: yes, I am using Eclipse/STS and set breakpoints in both methods. `setPresenter` is called with a _correct_ `Presenter` instance. In `handleSettingsClick` the private `presenter` field is null.

Comment: @TonySkulk Is it possible for you to create small working example project which can demonstrate this problem? Because it is certainly caused by something, what it is not demonstrated in your question. The only case (assuming that you haven't overlooked something)is that there is actually some JSNI code which erases presenter field directly.

Comment: I found a workaround calling `setPresenter` in my `EntryPoint` class. Althought injecting the presenter into the component should probably be done in the corresponding activity´s constructor, I can´t figure out why it doesn´t work there. Even if I add a button that just invokes the `setPresenter` method of the `LoginWidget`, the presenter will still be _null_.